# Why it is not entering inside if condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement, type-conversion, conditional-statements, unsigned

I was solving a problem on Geeksforgeeks for finding the largest word in the dictionary. I wrote the code accordingly but stuck in between as the flow is not entering inside if statement of inner 2nd for loop inside the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lcs(string s,string target)
{
    int m = s.size(),n = target.size();
    int dp[m+1][n+1];
    for(int i = 0;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(i ==0 || j ==0)
                dp[i][j] = 0;
            else if(s[i] == target[j])
            {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + 1;
            }
            else
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
    return dp[m][n];
}
int main() {
    //code
    int t,n,loc=0,MaX = -999;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i= 0;i < t;i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        string s[n];
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>s[j];
        }
        string target;
        cin>>target;

        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++)
        { 
            int Lcs = lcs(s[j],target);
            cout<<"s["<<j<<"] s[j] size-> "<<s[j].size()<<" lcs size -> "<<Lcs<<" MaX value->"<<MaX<<"\n";

            // It is not entering inside this if condition
            if((s[j].size() > MaX) && (s[j].size() == Lcs))
            {
                cout<<"enter inside loop\n";
                MaX = s[j].size();
                loc = j;
            }
        }

        cout<<s[loc]<<"\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

For input:

```
2
4
ale apple monkey plea
abpcplea
4
pintu geeksfor geeksgeeks forgeek
geeksforgeeks
```

the output is like this:

```
s[0] s[j] size-> 3 lcs size -> 3 MaX value->-999
s[1] s[j] size-> 5 lcs size -> 5 MaX value->-999
s[2] s[j] size-> 6 lcs size -> 2 MaX value->-999
s[3] s[j] size-> 4 lcs size -> 4 MaX value->-999
ale
s[0] s[j] size-> 5 lcs size -> 1 MaX value->-999
s[1] s[j] size-> 8 lcs size -> 8 MaX value->-999
s[2] s[j] size-> 10 lcs size -> 10 MaX value->-999
s[3] s[j] size-> 7 lcs size -> 7 MaX value->-999
pintu
```

Expected output (ignoring debugging output):

```
apple
geeksgeeks
```

Comment: If you don't want the output produced by `cout<<"s["<<j<<"] s[j] size-> "<<s[j].size()<<" lcs size -> "<<Lcs<<" MaX value->"<<MaX<<"\n";` why did you code it?

Comment: @user207421: With respect, that's clearly just debugging output showing that the `if` *should* be `true` but isn't (and is, mysteriously, never entered).  I think this is a clear, well-posed question that is interesting in that the answer is pretty subtle.

Comment: Turn on the [compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8g_js9)

Comment: @Ayxan your suggestion is a lifesaver but I'm not getting these warnings, neither in geeksforgeeks compiler nor in my codeblocks compiler. Is there any way to turn them on.

Comment: @Ashishkumar use compiler specific flags to turn on warnings. For GCC, you can start with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're mixing signed and unsigned types: `s[j].size()` is unsigned whereas `MaX` is signed.

Specifically, on my platform (gcc on x86_64), `s[j].size()` is of type `unsigned long`.  When you compare `s[j].size()` with `MaX`, the latter gets converted to the type of the former since the former is wider.

**However, `unsigned long` cannot represent negative numbers such as `-999` (the initial value of `MaX`).**

One way to fix this is by explicitly converting `s[j].size()` to a signed type:

```
   for(int j = 0;j<n;j++)
   {
       int Lcs = lcs(s[j],target);
       int ssize = int(s[j].size());
       if(ssize > MaX && ssize == Lcs)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
```

Compiling with `-Wconversion` catches this:

```
NPE$ g++ -Wconversion test.cc
test.cc:50:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::__1::basic_string<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
      [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
               MaX = s[j].size();
                   ~ ~~~~~^~~~~~
(more warnings omitted)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It finally entered inside if statement. Well apart from I made one more mistake. I should have assigned MaX value equal to some negative value again in order to pass multiple test cases.